# Ad-Hoc provisioning profiles say "Certificate not installed" even though App Store profiles are ok?

Tags: ios, xcode, coronasdk, provisioning

I'm trying to build using Corona SDK, which I've been doing for a few years without any real provisioning profile issues.

I can build my release copies using the App Store profile. However if I try to build an adhoc copy to distribute to testers, it says "Certificate not installed".
Both the App Store and Ad-Hoc profiles were signed with the same certificate, and belong to the same team etc.

I've tried: 
Deleting my provisioning profiles from my machine and re-downloading them. 
Creating a new provisioning profile and using that.
Checking that I have the certificate in Keychain Access, and that it had a private key (which it did).

Both the adhoc and store profiles contain the same team ID (not sure what it's called, it's some random chars).

I was also trying to build the same project in Xcode yesterday, and the same issue was shown there.

Is this a known problem, and is there a known fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Corona SDK specific problem. The error was being caused by a fault in one of the daily builds, which I had been using for about a month with no problems. It simply didn't recognise new builds, and updating to a recent build fixed it.